# How to do an integration test for a material UI <Slider /> component with userEvent or fireEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui

I have been struggling trying to do an integration test on a material UI  component. I can target the slider, but have not successfully been able to move the slider and find the new value. Do you have any guidance on how to interact with this component and test that interaction?

```js
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Slider } from "@material-ui/core";

import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";

describe("SearchForm interaction", () => {
  it("should change value if slider is moved", () => {
    const minValue = 1;
    const maxValue = 8;
    const currentValue = 4;
    render(
      <Slider
        className="slider"
        min={minValue}
        max={maxValue}
        value={currentValue}
        onChange={jest.fn()}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        data-testid="numPlayer-slider"
      />
    );
    const slider = screen.getByTestId("numPlayer-slider");
    //userEvent.click(slider, )
  });
});
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out too. I think for now, I'm going to stick with fireEvent.change(slider, { target: { value: '2' } })

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with this, but something you could try is:

- Inspect element on a slider and check how values are stored in the html tag.
- If property value is being used perhaps you can try:

  `slider.value = INSERT VALUE`;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for trying to help a fellow user out. Howerver, this answer doesn't really seem to address the question. You can look at a question's tags to get some additional context and help determine if it is something you can provide a good, quality answer for. For example, this question is asking about "reactjs" and "testjs". You can also use tags to help find questions on subjects and technologies you are familiar with and can provide helpful, quality answers to.